How can i get this effect from the 80s?
Hi, I want to know how to get this effect that i found in some photos from the 80s with a soft glow/blur and dot effect, is very pretty.

The "dot effect" is just film grain?

using an arcane device like https://imback.eu

Also maybe diffraction? The blur on that looks pretty universal, but softer than the grain.

Soft glow/blur = low quality lens. Can be simulated in lots of like VSCO.
Dot effect = film grain. Can be simulated in lots of like VSCO.
Your image in particular seems to be cropped significantly compared to 35mm film and that reduces the quality significantly.

My guess:
Shoot color negative film of ISO 400 or so.  Do it in daylight. And compensate for the daylight by stopping down enough to ensure there's softening from diffraction, maybe f/16?
In this case it might also just be an old long telephoto lens with not great correction.
Once you have the image, scan it with some sort of film scanner (or camera with macro setup and film holder) good enough to capture some of the grain.  If you don't have one you could see if the film processing place can do low or no-correction scans.

if you want to go with digital, you can try a combination of a lens filter and some editing tricks.
for filters a medium black mist or glimmer filter would work great. a good old soft filter might also fit your liking and is cheaper, especially second hand - even cheaper and quite some fun is either a black or white piece of stocking over your lens, or a bit of vaseline (on any UV, skylight or whatever filter you have lying around - don't put it on the lens itself!). with this you can play around with more or less vaseline, also smearing a bit/a lot or only applying it to the center or only at the periphery gives interesting vintage effects.
filters often give a more beautiful and authentic effect than editing only.
in editing eg. in lightroom you can move the dehaze slider (or similar settings) to the left to increase haze and/or decrease contrast, and add a bit of grain. decreasing vibrance or saturation also enhances the vintage effect. you could search for free "film" presets, and have a look on what they do. the good ones selectively decrease vibrance on certain colors, among other things. if you are (or want to become) avid in photoshop, there are tutorials on youtube etc, doing sophisticated things with layers and blur etc, to introduce some sort of blooming effect and other things.
play around and try out everything, but remember that often subtle effects look more authentic and pleasing than more intense ones.

RE: Filters, I don't believe this is either a glimmerglass or black mist. Both will halate broadly and neither reduce resolution much at all. A net may give a vaguely similar effect, but stockings are actually extremely dense as far as nets go, and I don't think this is a net. Vaseline definitely isn't it.
"Diffusion" filters are actually pretty nuanced. You can see in this image on the man's decorations that there is very little halation; there is no starbursts evident at all, so it's almost surely not a net.

This may be a Tiffen Diffusion (brand name) sort of filter, the sorts with ripples or other variations on the surface of the filter which soften through refraction. But, I think it's just a long zoom lens, shot wide open, with the plane of focus behind the subjects. Maybe between the subjects and the building, or maybe slightly behind the face of the building we see - the human figures are softer than the wall appears, but they are also higher contrast, so I can't say for sure.

it's difficult to extrapolate what the original poster exactly means by "80ies effect", and i'd guess that it is even part of the question, to find out what aspect of the example image evokes which respective feeling.
the old zoom lens is a good input actually!

regarding filters the OP specifically asks for a "soft glow", which is exaclty what black mist and glimmerglass filters do. both are widely used in video and photography for getting a more analog look. how broadly they halate depends on their strenght, and the halation of even a medium one would still be sublte in that image (lacking pronounced highlights). you are right that they do not reduce resolution - again depending on what exactly the OP wants to achieve.
stockings do indeed produce quite similar results to the example photo, google for examples.

@George Fiedler If OP provided an example, the best I can do is use it. Nearly every possibly effect that softens an image is described as a "soft glow" by those who don't deal with it very often - that's not a problem, but I think it's unwise to read "soft glow" and recommend a black mist or glimmerglass when neither would produce any result at all like the example provided. There are tools specifically designed to produce the effect OP is depicting.

I use filtration extensively, all sorts of it depending on the precise look I want. I use nets for probably half of all my photography, and I've used stockings on a few occasions; while a black net could give an effect in the ballpark of OP's example, it's still pretty far off the mark, and stockings are extremely heavy and will give no such look at all.

I am making perhaps a bigger deal out of this than I should, because I find that nearly any query about a "look" which is soft, glowing, or otherwise anything but tack sharp and high-contrast is met with the same recommendations -- the black mist, vaseline, stockings, stopping down excessively to diffract. These are tools, but they are far from the only tools, and overwhelmingly not the correct tools for the job specified. Catch Me If You Can for example would look totally different had most scenes used a promist instead of a net, or a stocking instead of a "darker" net, or what have you.

@spunky_h0rn solid knowledge typed here! i think our difference in position on the example stems from what we expect the OP to "mean". your answers aim to most exactly replicate the example given, expecting the OP to know what they are actually and specifically looking for. my answers expect the OP to basically want a photo that looks like from the 80ies, somewhat like the example given. therefor trying to aim them at easy accessible and well working tools to achieve such effects - not necessarily that exact look, but a similar look, or rather many similar looks.

in a way, since the OP hasn't bothered to comment anymore, and has given rather little info about what exactly they are looking for, i guess all our thoughts are kinda lost in space anyways though......
